# What is the difference between setActivity and setPresence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As seen in [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67733731), my code in the main post had been using `setActivity` to give my Discord bot a playing status. However, some playing status codes I found on Stack Overflow used `setPresence`. So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Look at the discord.js docs [setActivity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) and [setPresence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence)

Comment: I get it now. `setActivity` is a PLAYING status, and `setPresence` is Online. Invisible, D&D, Idle.

Answer (score 0):

They are basicly the same, with both you can set a playing/watching etc. status. But with the setPresence you can also set the Online, Invisible, Do Not Disturb and Idle for your bot. Here is are some examples:

```
client.user.setActivity(`a game`, {type: 'PLAYING'});
// will set the bot's activity to 'Playing a game' with the status online

bot.user.setPresence({
   status: 'dnd',
   activity: {
      name: 'a video',
       type: 'WATCHING'
    }
 });
 // will set the bot's activity to 'Watching a video' with the status Do Not Disturb
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [@mmoomocow's](https://stackoverflow.com/u/14526373/) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67734726/#comment119726756_67734726), `setPresence` just has the four basic statuses (Online, Idle, Do Not Disturb, Invisible).

`setActivity` has the Playing Statuses.

EDIT: This needs to be more detailed. You see,

```js
client.user.setActivity('status', {type: 'PLAYING'});
```

is the same as,

```js
client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'online',
    activity: {
        name: 'status',
        type: 'PLAYING
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, the difference between `setActivity()` and `setPresence()` is that activities are part of presences.

User Presences are broken up into several settings: user status (online/invisible/idle/dnd/streaming), activity (what the user is playing, streaming, listening to, etc.), and client status (whether the user is on web, mobile, or desktop). So with `setPresence`, you can interact with all of these settings, whereas with `setActivity`, you can only interact with the activity component.

You can see everything that makes up Presences [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence).